# A manga/manhwa that starts with a man drinking coffee and breaking the fourth wall

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was a manga or manhwa that went like this:

There was a guy drinking his coffee and giving a backstory of how he got stuck in this thing. And how he knows how the book or timeline goes.

Then he checks and realizes on the newspaper that the hero and hero’s party die. Then later on, the guy finds a young boy who was the son of a prostitute who is really smart and he was able to make predictions to make himself very rich.

Then after that they went and found another person who always keeps his eyes closed. When opened the eyes give out a 'demonic killing intent' thingy. The kid always was passive and so didn't want to have to go along with his killing intent.

The Main character stops him from going mad cause the other irrelevant guy was trying to kill the demon eyed kid’s sister. Afterwards they went to a yakuza-like place which they find another companion but the companion is a woman and the daughter of this big group.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Take a look a round and check out the [tour]! It teaches you about [ask] and [answer] and how accepting answers work. Have you seen the advice given [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)? You should add more details like language, colour/BW and when the manga is from.

Comment: @PDA Panda - Was this story in full colour or mostly black & white? What kind of world was the story set in? Medieval? Modern? Futuristic? And was the main character native to this world, or were they transported there from another world?

Comment: It was definitely colour, medieval, and i believe the guy was transported from another world

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this, and how many chapters were available at the time? Does the main character die before ending up in another world (i.e. is this reincarnation or just transmigration)? You mention companions; is this an adventure-type story? Do you remember what weapons they use? Swords? Magic? Guns?

Comment: I read about over 100 chapters i believe. I believe he transmigrated into another world. I believe it’s an adventure type story. And there is definetly swords and magic in it

Answer (score 1):

This is [Ernak](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=148800) ?

You remember all the plot of the manhwa for c100. All the plot matches Ernak so I 99% believe you just recently read it.

I will leave the main image here hope you can remember it

[image: https://cdn.mangaupdates.com/image/i312126.png]

Comment: Yep thank you so heckking much

Comment: @PDAPanda: You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].